# Angular 2 file upload with Spring-data-rest

Tags: angular, angular2-services, spring-data-rest

I have a simple application in agular 2. I need to send to server a *Pub* object that contains an image. But it does'n work. I don't know if the error is in client or in the server.

My server is simple, is in spring-data-rest. Others objects without file is working. But the object *Pub*  ([here](https://github.com/jordaos/library-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/br/ufc/library/pubs/Pub.java)) doesn't work. The attribute "image" is *byte[]* type.

When I try to send this object (with Angular 2), I get the following error:

`Failed to decode VALUE_STRING as base64 (MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS): Illegal character '.' (code 0x2e) in base64 content\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5194e239; line: 15, column: 20]
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5194e239; line: 15, column: 12] (through reference chain: br.ufc.library.pubs.Pub[\"image\"])`

The method that I send the object is `postWithFile` in [this](https://github.com/jordaos/library-front-web/blob/master/src/app/pub/pub.service.ts) file

Comment: the error is on server side as it says `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5194e239`. Its error at org.apache and its a server error

Comment: are you encoding image to base 64?

Comment: @ArslanAnjum I only do this: `pub.image = (files[0], files[0].name);` to send the image

Comment: basically spring data rest is expecting that if it recieves a byte array it would be base64 encoded. try encoding the image to base64 and then sending it to server. I dont have much knowledge about Angular 2, but try if you could declare pub.image to be a byte array rather than File.

Comment: default behavior of spring data rest to expect base64 can be overriden but that depends on your knowledge of spring. Basically you have to override halObjectMapper and add a custom deserializer for byte[]. add a custom serializer also then.